# Select individuals that are in multiple groups in r

Tags: r, string, select, grouping

I'm (very) new to R and trying to select individual users who are in multiple groups. I have two string variables - 
So, considering the sample data below --

```
user <- c("User1", "User2", "User1", "User3","User4", 
          "User5", "User3", "User6", "User7", "User8", "User5")
place <- c("PlaceA", "PlaceA", "PlaceB", "PlaceB", "PlaceC", 
           "PlaceC", "PlaceC", "PlaceC", "PlaceD", "PlaceD", "PlaceD")
users_df <- data.frame(user, place)
```

I need something that allows me to find which users occur in more than one specific group, e.g.:

- which Users are in `PlaceA` that are also in `PlaceB`, or
- which Users are in `PlaceB` and `PlaceC` and `PlaceD`, or
- which users are in [`PlaceB` AND (`PlaceC` OR `PlaceD`)]?

Ideally, I would like to funnel the relevant rows into a separate dataframe, so that for that first example, the new dataframe would look like --

```
User1   PlaceA
User1   PlaceB
```

But in contrast to the data here, the actual data have about 25,000 observations, several more variables, and about 5,000 unique names of people that can occur in up to 43 groups/places.

I have tried different uses of `unique`, `%in%`, `which`, and `str_which`, but I'm just completely lost... Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
users_df %>% group_by(user) %>% filter(n() > 1)
```

This will give you what you want---note that you are grouping by `user` and getting all instances where there's more than one instance.

Let me take you to your final output step by step (which clarifies things for me as well.) Now, as in your comment, if you do not care about users who appear multiple times in a single group, that simply changes to

```
users_df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  group_by(user, place) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1)
```

If you are more specific about your conditions, for instance, users that are in A & B:

```
## Use the `filter(n() == 1)` as necessary
users_df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  dplyr::filter(place %in% c("PlaceA", "PlaceB")) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)
```

The case in your last comment: in (A & B) | (C & D & E). This seems tricky, but we can get creative with `lapply`.

```
lapply(
  list(
    paste0("Place", c("A", "B")),
    paste0("Place", c("C", "D", "E"))
  ), function(x)
    users_df %>%
    group_by(user) %>%
    filter(place %in% c(x)) %>%
    filter(n() == length(x) & n() > 1)
) %>% 
  bind_rows()
```

A combination of the above code can get you what you want.

Comment: thanks! That gets partly there because it gives me people who occur more than once, but unfortunately, these users can occur more than once within the same group (which I don't care about), and this doesn't really allow me to select the groups. What I'd like to be able to do is select those users who occur in multiple specific groups - e.g. Group A and Group B only OR Groups C and D and E (but I don't want to select them if they happen to be in Group A and Group F, for example). I can find people who appear multiple times, but I need a way to be more specific  :)  Sorry if I was unclear!

Comment: I really appreciate all the effort, but I don't think this works... I'm most interested in your second answer for specific conditions [users_df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  dplyr::filter(place %in% c("PlaceA", "PlaceB")) %>%
  filter(n() > 1] On this very basic data set, it does work, but on the extended dataset, it appears simply to filter the data down to the two relevant places and select all of those who have more than one entry (regardless of whether both entries are in the same place). It doesn't appear to specifically select those who have at least one entry in BOTH places...

Comment: @Emi I've already commented that you want to use it in combination with the first code---see the comment up there?

Comment: I do see! I misunderstood what you meant, you're exactly right. Thank you, the following worked perfectly for me:  users_df1 <- users_df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  group_by(user, place) %>% 
  filter(n() == 1)

users_df2 <- users_df1 %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  dplyr::filter(place %in% c("PlaceA", "PlaceB")) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)

Comment: I altered things a bit for when I want to include those with multiple entries in a group, should anyone come along with the same question: newdata <- users_df %>% 
  group_by(user) %>%
  filter(n() > 1) %>% 
  group_by(user, place)%>% 
  distinct(user, place)%>% 
  group_by(user) %>% dplyr::filter(place %in% c("PlaceA", "PlaceB")) %>%
  filter(n() > 1)

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to create your data like this (same result but you don't end up with random named vectors in your global environment):

```
 users_df <- data.frame(
 user = c("User1", "User2", "User1", "User3","User4", "User5", "User3", "User6", "User7", "User8", "User5"),
 place  = c("PlaceA", "PlaceA", "PlaceB", "PlaceB", "PlaceC", "PlaceC", "PlaceC", "PlaceC", "PlaceD", "PlaceD", "PlaceD"))
```

Then use the base function `split` which has a method for dataframes:

```
group_by_user <- split(users_df, users_df$user)
group_by_user  #output not included

 sapply( group_by_user, function(df) length( unique(df$place) ) )
User1 User2 User3 User4 User5 User6 User7 User8 
    2     1     2     1     2     1     1     1
```

Alternative use if the count of used by `place` desired:

```
> grouped_data <- split(users_df, users_df$place)
> grouped_data
$PlaceA
   user  place
1 User1 PlaceA
2 User2 PlaceA

$PlaceB
   user  place
3 User1 PlaceB
4 User3 PlaceB

$PlaceC
   user  place
5 User4 PlaceC
6 User5 PlaceC
7 User3 PlaceC
8 User6 PlaceC

$PlaceD
    user  place
9  User7 PlaceD
10 User8 PlaceD
11 User5 PlaceD
```

Then you can select by `place` name like this:

```
> grouped_data[['PlaceB']]
   user  place
3 User1 PlaceB
4 User3 PlaceB
```

Or you can loop over the list of dataframes like this:

```
lapply( grouped_data, nrow)
$PlaceA
[1] 2

$PlaceB
[1] 2

$PlaceC
[1] 4

$PlaceD
[1] 3


> sapply( grouped_data, nrow)
PlaceA PlaceB PlaceC PlaceD 
     2      2      4      3
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty confused by the above... From what I can tell, this just tells me how many people are in each place/group, which I can get with a summary function... I'm not sure how this relates to my needing to identify people who have entries in two separate places and not just those who have multiple entries. I can filter my data set down to the places I'm interested in, what I need is a way to know when an individual has entries in two or more **specific** places. If that is what's above, I'm sorry, it's gone way over my head.

Comment: @42 we can still use `split`. Just run it on *user* instead of *place*, then filter the list: `df_list <- split(users_df, users_df$user); Filter(function(sub) NROW(sub) > 1, df_list)`. Run a `do.call(rbind, ...)` if OP needs a single dataframe.

Comment: Appears I misunderstood the question and Parfait has answered your question. I'll edit my response.